# How is Revit database structured?

Tags: revit-api, revit

I was looking for a conceptual structure of Revit models. I found the following graph which seems to be from 2009. I wonder if it is still valid.

[image: revit project structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is still a (very nice and) valid representation of the main Revit database structure.

Thank you for sharing that!

Here is a Revit 2010 API class diagram:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/01/no-revit-api-class-diagram.html

However, it has not been officially updated since then. You can use the built-in Visual Studio tools to navigate through and explore the class structure at need:

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/03/split-personality-and-revit-api-class-diagram.html#3